# HP Proliant SE316M1 server blinking red health LED and system suddenly shuts down?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I've recently acquired a HP Proliant SE316M1 as a used server. I've never owned such server before. The server has both power supplies, 2 CPU's and 4 sticks of memory totalling 16GB. I believe it's quite an old server. When I turn the server on, with both power plugs connected the health light flashes amber for about 2 mintues and the system boots, then, the blinking amber light turns into a blinking red light and all of a sudden at a random point in time the system appears to shut down, my connected screen goes off completely and the fans spin at a low speed, all the while the red blinking light continues.

What might this be and how can I get it to be a solid green light?

Comment: I believe this is a variant of DL160 G6. If your system boots to BIOS (e.g. video initializes and you see a prompt to configure iLO by pressing F8) you should reset iLO settings and configure network/password settings. If it does not, follow the procedure of NVRAM reset, connect iLO port to network and use default iLO settings to access it. From there you should see health status of your components.

Comment: power up your server and get into the ilo. you may check your hardware health through ilo access. also this type of issues are mostly caused by RAM modules.